# Transform DBIO Value to Custom Case Class

Tags: scala, slick

I have a `DBIO[Seq[tuple]]` and I would like to map it to `DBIO[Seq[customCaseClass]]`.

I am aware that I could do the transformation on the `db.run()` result with something like: `customCaseClass.tupled(row)` ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35336486/4822174)). However, I am interested in composing the `DBIO` return value in varying functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three places where you can do this: at the `Query` level, `DBIO` level, and (as you noted, and rejected) at the `Future` level.

### Query

At the query level, the conversion will happen as part of the execution of the query on Slick's own execution context.

It would look something like this:

```
// Given some query that returns a tuple...
val tupleQ: Query[(Rep[String],Rep[String]), (String,String), Seq] =
   table.map{ row => (row.column1, row.column2) }

// ...which we'd like to project into this:
case class SomeCaseClass(v1: String, v2: String)

// ...we can use the mapTo macro to generate the conversion:
val ccQ: Query[Rep[SomeCaseClass], SomeCaseClass, Seq] =
   tupleQ.map{ _.mapTo[SomeCaseClass] }
```

If this was all you're doing, then maybe the default projection (`def * ...`) is the place for this.

If you need more control over the conversion logic, you can use the lower-level `<>` in place of `mapTo`. [Section 5.2 of Essential Slick](http://books.underscore.io/essential-slick/essential-slick-3.html#projections-provenshapes-mapto-and) gives more detail on this.

### DBIO

The question was specifically about `DBIO`. The conversion there is going to run on your own execution context.

That would look something like this:

```
// Given a DBIO that returns a tuple...
val tupleD: DBIO[Seq[(String,String)]] =
  table.map(row => (row.column1, row.column2)).result

// ... we can use any of the DBIO combinators to convert it, such as map:
val ccD: DBIO[Seq[SomeCaseClass]] =
  dQ.map{ pairs => pairs.map{ case (a, b) => SomeCaseClass(a,b) } }
```

(...or `dQ.map(pairs => pairs.map(SomeCaseClass.tupled))` as you noted).

The two big benefit you get at this level are:

1. you have access to the values, such as `(a,b)`, and so can make decisions about what you want to do with the values.
2. being part of an action means you could take part in a transcation.

[Chapter 4 of Essential Slick](http://books.underscore.io/essential-slick/essential-slick-3.html#combining) lists out many of the DBIO combinators. The [Slick Manual](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.3/dbio.html) also describes the combinators.

### Future

The final place is in the `Future`, which looks very much like the `DBIO` version but after the `db.run` (as you've already found).

Comment: Wow, elegant simple solution. I had seen Ch4 of Essential Slick but it didn't click for some reason.